# Is there a way to display a notification every time you change the keyboard layout?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to show a (notify-osd) notification every time the keyboard layout is changed?

I have a laptop with a screen with not enough resolution to have tons/10+ indicators, and space for the title bar of windows, and I want to eliminate the keyboard indicator required when you have multiple keyboards.

I'm using Unity on 13.04.

Comment: It's possible to show notifications. I also had in mind changing the launcher color, because notifications are easy to miss. Would you still be interested in such solution ?

Comment: @Serg Unfortunately, I have moved on from Ubuntu to Arch, and the tiny 4:3 laptop has been relegated to dumb terminal duty (it does admirably). I also completely abandoned using different keyboard layouts because it's annoying, and switched to just using a compose key.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script called `notify-kbd-layout.sh` and symlinked it to `/usr/bin`: `sudo ln -s ./notify-kbd-layout.sh /usr/bin/notify-kbd-layout`

Obligatory source code:

```
if [ "$(xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67)" = '00000000' ] 
  then
  notify-send 'Current Keyboard Layout:' 'US (English)'
fi
if [ "$(xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67)" = '00001000' ]
  then
  notify-send 'Current Keyboard Layout:' 'CMS (French)'
fi
```

Then, I went into Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Custom, and added a shortcut for <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to run `notify-kbd-layout`.

Comment: Could you please explain the different commands? I have 3 different layouts and  `xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67)` always return the same number., `00000000`. To be honest, it gave me a different value (`'00000002') only the first time I executed it, still don't know why.

Comment: @tigerjack89 I have no idea how it works anymore. Try http://explainshell.com

Answer (score 0):

You do not say if you use unity or something else. I use cairo-dock, and I stick not so often used icons in a sub-dock to save space. 
Cairo-dock also has extensions such as has a notification-area and notification-area-old which capture several indicators (dropbox, WiFi, keyboard) in one icon. Clicking on the icon gives the usual results. 
I don't use this because with the current theme the composite icon is half transparent and not very visible.

Comment: notify-osd hints that I use unity.

Comment: Notify-osd works in my distribution without using unity. There are some patches for notify-osd, see [here for older](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html) and [here for recent versions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html) of Ubuntu.